# How to create initializer to create and migrate mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql, migration, entity-framework-4.3, initializer

I have been learning how to use EF for a week or so now and am stuck on the issue of creating/updating my database. I am able to create an initializer to create the database if it is not there:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<GumpDatabase>(new GumpDatabaseInitializer());
....

class GumpDatabaseInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<GumpDatabase>
{
    public GumpDatabaseInitializer()
    {
    }
    protected override void Seed(GumpDatabase context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Name ON Stations (Name)");
        // Other stuff
    }
}
```

Or I can create a Configuration to migrate the db

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<GumpDatabase>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<GumpDatabase, Configuration>());
....

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<GumpDatabase>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator()); 
    }

    protected override void Seed(GumpDatabase context)
    {

    }
```

Each works correctly but I haven't figured out a way to do both. I can switch between the two initializers by changing the SetInitializer call but if I want to create the database if it is not there and also migrate it if it is what do I do?  Do I need to create a custom initializer?

Thanks

**Edit based on NSGaga answer**

```
class CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer<TContext, TConfiguration> : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>, IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
{
    private readonly DbMigrationsConfiguration _configuration;
    public CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer()
    {
        _configuration = new TConfiguration();
    }
    public CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer(string connection)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection), "connection");

        _configuration = new TConfiguration
        {
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connection)
        };
    }
    void IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        Contract.Requires(context != null, "context");

        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
            if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
            {
                var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
                migrator.Update();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Database.Create();
            Seed(context);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
    protected virtual void Seed(TContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<GumpDatabase>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator()); 
    }

    protected override void Seed(GumpDatabase context)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
class GumpDatabaseInitializer : CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer<GumpDatabase,Gump.Migrations.Configuration>
{
    public GumpDatabaseInitializer()
    {
    }
    protected override void Seed(GumpDatabase context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Name ON Stations (Name)");
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Name ON Sequences (Name)");
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX StationPartNumber ON StationPartNumbers (StationId,PartNumberId)");
    }
}
```

and finally

```
static void Main()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<GumpDatabase>(new GumpDatabaseInitializer());
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you're pretty much there - you can lookup the source code for `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` (it's open source http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) - it's pretty simplistic, what it does pretty much is call the `DbMigrator` - as far as I could see.

All you have to do seems is to merge the two - use one or the other as a basis, add other functionality in there - that should work fine I think.

```
class CreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer<TContext, TConfiguration> : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>, IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> 
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
{
    private readonly DbMigrationsConfiguration _configuration;
    public CreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer()
    {
        _configuration = new TConfiguration();
    }
    public CreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer(string connection)
    {
        Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connection), "connection");

        _configuration = new TConfiguration
        {
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(connection)
        };
    }
    void IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        Contract.Requires(context != null, "context");

        var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
        migrator.Update();

        // move on with the 'CreateDatabaseIfNotExists' for the 'Seed'
        base.InitializeDatabase(context);
    }
    protected override void Seed(TContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

call it like this...

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer<GumpDatabase, YourNamespace.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

...actually, override it (since it's generic implementation) like you were doing for `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` (you just have extra 'param' for Configuration)  - and just supply the 'Seed'.

```
class GumpDatabaseInitializer : CreateAndMigrateDatabaseInitializer<GumpDatabase, YourNamespace.Migrations.Configuration>
{
    protected override void Seed(GumpDatabase context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Name ON Stations (Name)");
    }
}
```

...and call it something like

```
Database.SetInitializer(new GumpDatabaseInitializer());
```

**EDIT:** 
Based on the comments - DbMigrator should not run twice. It always checks (spends a bit of time) and does a 'blank' update and moves on. However just in case if you'd like to remove that and 'check' before entering - this should work (change the similar piece above)...

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
    if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
        migrator.Update();
```

(this is a redundant / double-check - one of the if-s should be enough. Put a break there - and see exactly what's happening, it should not get in - once Db is migrated. As I mentioned, works fine when I test it.

**EDIT:**

Replace the inside of `InitializeDatabase` with...

```
var doseed = !context.Database.Exists();
// && new DatabaseTableChecker().AnyModelTableExists(context);
// check to see if to seed - we 'lack' the 'AnyModelTableExists' - could be copied/done otherwise if needed...

var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
// if (doseed || !context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
    if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
        migrator.Update();

// move on with the 'CreateDatabaseIfNotExists' for the 'Seed'
base.InitializeDatabase(context);
if (doseed)
{
    Seed(context);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works around (half-way) not-seeding - if migration goes first. And migrations have to be first, otherwise you have issues.

You still need to do it properly - this is the gist if not all you might need - but if any issues w/ MySQL etc., probably some more leg work here.

**Note:** Still seeding doesn't call if you have a db, but it's empty. Problem is mixing of the two different initializers. So you'll have to work that out - either by implementing what Create... does inside (that call we can't call) or something else.

Comment: Would you happen to know where to get source for EF 4.3.1? The Microsoft site only has 5 or 6.

Comment: I think they've gone 'open source' only for new updates (i.e. EF 6) - but the source should be the same - regarding this at least. If you have `DbMigrator` that's pretty much it

Comment: It looks like there are some missing pieces:     `using System.Data.Entity.Config;
    using System.Data.Entity.Internal;
    using System.Data.Entity.Resources;
    using System.Data.Entity.Utilities;` not found in EF 4.3.1.

Comment: Just try the DbMigrator...Update - that's it I think - you have that, I think. If you have MigrateDatabase... initializer

Comment: thanks, I am 99% there. The database is created and is migrated successfully - but only once. After a migration when I rerun the app it thinks that the database is unmigrated and tries to apply the changes again.  This is what I have for the migrate code:             `if (context.Database.Exists())
            {
                if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
                {
                    var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
                    migrator.Update();
                }
            }`  Would you have any ideas?

Comment: I hope I do get an accept/upvote for this at least :) - I'll check...You could add another `if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))` before you proceed to migration. Or just `reverse` and override migrator. I don't expect that migration to run twice - that migrator works fine

Comment: Of course! See the edit I just made. It still has the problem I mentioned: 1 - delete db, 2 - run app, new db is created OK, 3 - modify model, 4 - run app, db is updated OK, 5 - run app, migrator.Update() fails because it tries to migrate the database again. The code looks just like the source from Microsoft, but obviously something is not getting saved or updated.

Comment: Unfortunately it still fails, just in a different way. There are never any pending migrations so it always skips the migrate() call. Possibly it could be a bug in the MySQL connector (6.6.5), it wouldn't be the first.

Comment: There was a problem w/ empty Db (i.e. none) - I made a change - migration has to go first (you cannot change the order) - and then seeding doesn't work. You'll have to do the rest, this as much I had time fast over this, more than I wanted :) cheers

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should be:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false) || migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
    migrator.Update();
```

because if we have a migration, that is not related to our db model, for example inserting a row in any of our tables, the migration won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

To do both (seed and migrate) you really only have to use migrations with a `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer. When you enable migrations for your context a `Configuration` class derived from `DbMigrationsConfiguration` is created and you can override the [`Seed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt177875(v=vs.113).aspx) method to seed your database. Note that the database may already contain seed data when this method executes but the [`AddOrUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbsetmigrationsextensions.addorupdate(v=vs.113).aspx) extension method conveniently helps you make "upserts" in your database.

This is different compared to the `Seed` method of some of the other database intitializers where the database is only seeded when it is initially created. However, when you are using migrations you may want to change your seed data when the database changes and using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` makes that possible.

To combine seeding with migrations you will have to perform the following steps in a new project:

1. Create a code-first `DbContext` with associated entities
2. In the package manager console execute the command `Enable-Migrations`
3. In the `Migrations` folder a `Configuration` class is generated with a `Seed` method. You can modify this method to seed your database:

   ```
   protected override void Seed(MyContext context) {
     // Add two entities with name "Foo" and "Bar".
     context.MyEntities.AddOrUpdate(
       e => e.Name,
       new MyEntity { Name = "Foo" },
       new MyEntity { Name = "Bar" }
     );
   }
   ```
4. You need to create a database initializer that derives from [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx):

   ```
   class MyContextInitializer
     : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Migrations.Configuration> { }
   ```

   You will also have to configure the initializer either by calling `Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInitializer())` when you application starts or in the `App.config` file by using the [`<databaseInitializer/>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Initializers) element.
5. In the constructor for the generated `Configuration` class you can enable automatic migrations:

   ```
   public Configuration() {
     AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true
   }
   ```

   However, in a team you might prefer to not do that. In that case you will have to create an initial migration (unless it was created when you did `Enable-Migrations`). In the package manager execute the command `Add-Migration InitialCreate`. This creates the first migration required to create your database.

At this point you have a `DbContext` with migrations and a `Seed` method.

So to sum it: Enable migrations, use the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer and add seed data in the `Configuration` class that was generated when migrations were enabled.

Answer (score 0):

While **MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion** does actually create the DB if it does not exist and even allows you to seed it, if you already have a working solution based on **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists** and/or don't want to complicate it with testing for existence of seed data, you can just use the below by inheriting from it rather than from **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists**:

```
public class CreateOrMigrateDatabaseInitializer<TContext, TConfiguration> : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>, IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>
        where TContext : DbContext
        where TConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext>, new()
    {

        void IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        {
            if (context.Database.Exists())
            {
                if (!context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata: false))
                {
                    var migrationInitializer = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TConfiguration>(true);
                    migrationInitializer.InitializeDatabase(context);
                }
            }

            base.InitializeDatabase(context);
        }
    }
```

This is based on previous answers and OP's own solution. This should work with other providers as well, but I only tested with SQL Server.