# How to get current migration name via code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there a way for code in my ASP.NET MVC 4, code-first EF app to retrieve the current migration name?  I want to display the migration name on an administrator's status page just as a sanity check to verify that the expected migration(s) have been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DbMigrator` ([DbMigrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.103).aspx)) class for that.

e.g.

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);
var pending = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
var all = migrator.GetLocalMigrations();
```

Where `_configuration` is your `Configuration` class under the `Migraiton` dir.

You need to experiment a bit - see which actually fits your bill.

> Also, I'm suggesting that you make an 'initializer' instead of just
>   adding that into the code. As that's how it's usually done, and a
>   'natural spot' for those things to happen (you don't 'call it', it
>   'calls you').

**Check this link for an implementation of a custom initializer** - which includes some DbMigrator code.
[How to create initializer to create and migrate mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796115/how-to-create-initializer-to-create-and-migrate-mysql-database/15796416#15796416)

Comment: It works perfect but it takes more than 30 seconds to response. any suggestions please??

Comment: It's probably your setup (too many migrations or Db etc.), is all I can think of. Generally, this isn't something you should do on normal app runs, when performance is an issue, but on occasional maintenance or setup or something.